# Can we merge QT, boost and other libraries in one program

Tags: qt, boost

This is a naive question from beginner level learner.

I need to implement GUI + making images from the .bin files and data from FPGA, Hence I think I need to use QT and boost and other relevant libraries(3rd party). but I am not sure which one now.

Now my question is if I add them together in one program using Visual Studio C++ does it affect the performance in terms of speed of execution or otherwise...

Might it have any side effects?

Comment: Everything in a program affects the speed of execution or otherwise. The question is does it affect them in an unforeseen way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Qt, Boost, 3rd party libs, the STL and so on without any problems. You'll have no impact on performance by using different libraries from different sources, however if you're using Qt you'll find it duplicates a lot of what boost does so you'd be best picking one or the other unless you need some of the very specific Boost libraries.

Answer (score 1):

With most programs you need to be first concerned that you can correctly solve the problem. Once you have a solution you can evaluate if the solution meets your performance expectations. There are always things that can be tweaked to improve performance.

As a general rule I think you are going to see that most of the noticeable performance issues are going to be a direct result of your own coding limitations and not some inherent slowness within the libraries mentioned. Things I have seen include doing too much work on the UI thread, inefficient looping over large collections, creating objects within loops and database queries that deal with too much information.

Remember what Donald Knuth had to say about optimization:

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

In your case, since it sounds like you have never solved this type of problem before, most of your effort should be spent on just finding a solution. Version 1.0 is about solving the problem. Version 2.0 can be used to deliver a better experience.